# Adminium plugin

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, server-administration

I am running a Bukkit server with the TCAdmin panel and I would like to use the Adminium app on my iPod to control it remotely.

I got the JSONAPI plugin installed and configured and enter all the correct settings into the app, but it will not connect. I think the port might be blocked.

Is there any way to open ports in the TCAdmin panel?

Comment: I'm assuming it gave an error message, if so, could you show it to us?

Comment: Another thing, JSONAPI is an [API](http://www.google.com/search?q=api&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-beta). Meaning you need another plugin or something for it to be effective. There might be a plugin out there that does what your looking for but if not, the [JSONAPI wiki](https://github.com/alecgorge/jsonapi/wiki) says it supports JavaScript, Python, PHP, and .NET so if you know one of those, that shouldn't matter. And lastly, you will need an iPod application for the other end (unless you will do that via the web), which there probably is.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a plugin for it to work properly. For instance, I use the RemoteToolKit Bukkit plugin, and then connect to port 25561 to remotely see the console (after unblocking port 25561 as well).

Comment: If this answer is acceptable, you should mark it with the check on the side

Answer (score 0):

You may need to port forward the jsonapi port 25059 (I think) the same one you port forwarded for your Minecraft server.